# No browsing issue on PPTP VPN Server on CentOS 6 64bit

Tags: vpn, centos, pptp

I am trying to setup a VPN server in CentOS 6 64-bit.
I used the first 4 steps of following document to setup the server in [How-to-setup-your-own-vpn-with-pptp](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-your-own-vpn-with-pptp).

And I successfully managed to setup the VPN. And I also managed to connect to the VPN from MacOS X. But the issue, is I can not browse anything. I can not ping to any site, except for I can only ping my VPN's Server IP. Other than that, which ever IP or site I ping, there is a 100% Packet loss.

I am sure something is wrong in my settings in my VPS, but not sure what it is. Any idea?

**Edit:**
I am on an openVZ container, and tun/tap is enabled.

Comment: Are you routing your HTTP/HTTPS traffic through the VPN?  You should provide configuration information for each device, otherwise it's hard to tell what the problem stems from.

Comment: If you mean, i selected to route all traffic over the VPN in my MacOS X settings, then yes i did that.

Comment: Like I said, without a network diagram or configurations it's going to be hard to determine what the root cause is.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, could you please guide me how can i provide you the network diagram or the required configurations?

Comment: Try `sudo reboot` and then rerun the `iptables` command.